# Have Button fire with both Kernel and FrontEnd

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, input, code-generation

Here's some code which, when evaluated, types an expression in the cell below it:

```
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[],Next,CellContents];Pause@.2;
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[],"1"];Pause@.2;
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[],"+"]; Pause@.2;
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[],"2"];Pause@.2;
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[],All,CellContents];Pause@.2;
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookApply[SelectedNotebook[],
  FractionBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]","\[Placeholder]"]];Pause@.2;
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], "3"];
```

Now I want to put it in a button, so I'll wrap it in `Button["type stuff",...]`.  But then it takes more than a second to see the full output due to *something about the front end and updates and kernels and what not*.

If instead I write `Button["type stuff",...,Evaluator->None]`, I find out that `Pause` is not a function available to the front end.

If I strip out all the `Pause`s, then it works great -- there is some delay -- I would just like to slow it down.

## Question

Is there a function available with no `Evaluator` that can slow it down?  Is there a way to switch `Evaluator`s while a `Button` function is running?  Or should I stick with kernel evaluation only and do something with `Dynamic` to get the progressive typing?

---

Extraneous questions:

- I tried to store the big typing code in a symbol, using `HoldForm` and `ReleaseHold` in the `Button` -- I didn't manage to get it right, the front end couldn't `ReleaseHold` the thing
- I tried to have a wait parameter `t` instead of `.2`, but again the front end couldn't reference the value of `t`, and I couldn't figure out how to inject `t` with a `Block` or something before creating the `Button`
- I tried to generate the code with a `Riffle[.../@Characters@"1+2",Pause@.2]`, but how to turn the resulting list into an "input expression" -- no, an "input cell" with some newlines -- no, an `Inactive@CompoundExpression@@...`, but how to `Activate` it without evaluating it... I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
typeStuff = 
  Module[{}, 
   Hold[FrontEndExecute@
     FrontEnd`SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], Next, CellContents]; 
    Pause@.2;
    FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], "1"]; 
    Pause@.2;
    FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], "+"]; 
    Pause@.2;
    FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], "2"]; 
    Pause@.2;
    FrontEndExecute@
     FrontEnd`SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], All, CellContents]; 
    Pause@.2;
    FrontEndExecute@
     FrontEnd`NotebookApply[SelectedNotebook[], 
      FractionBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"]]; 
    Pause@.2;
    FrontEndExecute@
     FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], "3"];]];

Button["ClickMe", ReleaseHold@typeStuff, Method -> "Queued"]
```

Comment: To parametrize the delay, change `Module[{ }, ...` to `Module[{t = 1}, ...` and replace the `0.2` by `t`. Or change `typeStuff` to a function that takes `t` as an argument.